# Custom control not able to be added programmatically

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, linq, custom-controls

I have created a custom control and want to be able to add it at run time but it is not working. I can add it through design view and it works fine. My code is below for the custom control and where I am adding it.

PluginControlButton.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace customControlLib
{
    public partial class PluginControlButton : Control
    {
        private Color color1 = Color.LightGray;
        private Color color2 = Color.Black;
        private Color color3 = Color.White;
        private Color colorU = Color.Yellow;
        private int cpSize = 70;
        private Image backgroundImage;
        /// <summary>
        /// The image for the plugin
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public Image PluginImage
        {
            get { return backgroundImage; }
            set { backgroundImage = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the component
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public int ComponentSize
        {
            get { return cpSize; }
            set
            {
                if (value == cpSize)
                    return;
                cpSize = value;
                cpSize = value;

                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the out ring
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public Color ProcessColor
        {
            get { return color1; }
            set { color1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the inside circle
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public Color InnerColor
        {
            get { return color2; }
            set { color2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the update circle
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public Color UpdateColor
        {
            get { return colorU; }
            set { colorU = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the text
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public Color textColor
        {
            get { return color3; }
            set { color3 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Plugin text
        /// </summary>
        [Category("PluginControlSettings")]
        public new string Text
        {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set
            {
                if (value == base.Text)
                    return;
                base.Text = value;

                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public PluginControlButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            this.Width = cpSize;
            this.Height = cpSize;
            Graphics gfx = pe.Graphics;
            Rectangle rc = ClientRectangle;
            rc.Width -= 1;
            rc.Height -= 1;
            Graphics gfx2 = pe.Graphics;
            Rectangle rc2 = ClientRectangle;
            rc2.Width -= 17;
            rc2.Height -= 17;
            rc2.Location = new Point(8, 8);
            Graphics gfxU = pe.Graphics;
            Rectangle rcU = ClientRectangle;
            rcU.Width -= 9;
            rcU.Height -= 9;
            rcU.Location = new Point(4, 4);
            gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Parent.BackColor), ClientRectangle);
            gfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(color1), rc);
            gfx.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Transparent, 1.0f), rc);
            gfxU.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(colorU), rcU);
            gfxU.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Transparent, 1.0f), rcU);
            gfx2.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(color2), rc2);
            gfx2.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Transparent, 1.0f), rc2);
            Font fnt = new Font(base.Font.FontFamily, base.Font.Size, base.Font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            gfx.DrawString(Text, fnt, new SolidBrush(color3), new RectangleF((float)(rc2.Left), (float)(rc2.Top), (float)(rc2.Width), (float)(rc2.Height)), sf);
            if (backgroundImage != null)
            {
                Graphics gfx3 = pe.Graphics;
                Rectangle rc3 = ClientRectangle;
                rc3.Width -= 35;
                rc3.Height -= 35;
                rc3.Location = new Point(17, 17);
                gfx3.DrawImage(backgroundImage, rc3);
                base.ForeColor = color2;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using customControlLib;

namespace GlassSquid2
{
    public partial class GlassSquidControl : Form
    {
        public GlassSquidControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void GlassSquidControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PluginControlButton pbc = new PluginControlButton();

            this.Controls.Add(pbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get at runtime?

Comment: Did you give the control a location and a size?  Never resize a canvas in a paint event — you only draw in that event, nothing else.

Comment: I tried giving it a location and a size. I am not getting any errors, nothing shows up is what the problem is. The form loads but the control will not load.

Comment: Code works for me when I give it a size.  Is the load event wired up?  I would probably move your code to the constructor, under the InitializeComponent line.

Comment: @JW12689 Try to call pbc.Visible = true after you created it.

Comment: @JW12689 If this doesn't work, you can add it in designer, open the designer file and watch what code the designer is adding. There must sth. you are missing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is working now, I had to add a size to the component. Thanks for the help.

```
customControlLib.PluginControlButton pbc = new customControlLib.PluginControlButton()
        {
            ComponentSize = 70,
            InnerColor = Color.Black,
            Name = "TEST",
            PluginImage = null,
            ProcessColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray,
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 70),
            Text = "Test",
            textColor = System.Drawing.Color.White,
            UpdateColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
        };
```